# How to deny access to specific port when destination is NOT a specific host?

Tags: iptables, hostname

I'm trying to DENY access to port 1000 when it is being accessed through any host or IP that is NOT a specific host.

I.e.
If I try to access the service on `sub.domain.com:1000` I *should* get in.
If I try to access the service on `sub.domain2.com:1000` I *should not* get in, even though both of these domains are A-records pointing to the same server.

I'm trying to accomplish this using iptables with the following rules, but it's not working. It's allowing connections to any destination host/ip, not just the one I have set an ACCEPT rule to.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination sub.domain.com --dport 1000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1000 -j DROP
```

The sub.domain2.com in this example, hosts different services, which is why I can't simply remove that DNS pointer.

Comment: Which part is "not working"?

Comment: Oh right, sorry. I guess I should have been more specific. I've updated my question

Comment: Well I though it was easy but after some search it seems that iptables is not the tool to use in that case.

Comment: Any idea which tool I should be using?..

Comment: iptables is the wrong tool for this. The hostname is up higher in the OSI stack, iptables can only operate on the lower level. If it's a webserver, you can use Nginx or Apache to control access based on the hostname, for example. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model

Comment: Although iptables will not do this, you can do it with apache. See http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-restrict-access-based-on-ip-address-to-selected-directories/ and http://serverfault.com/questions/323610/can-i-restrict-a-vhost-to-only-a-local-ip/323611#323611

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IPTables is working on IP and TCP level, so it doesn't actually know DNS.

When a client creates a TCP connection to a DNS name it first looks up the IP address corresponding to the DNS name and then connects to the IP, not to the DNS name.

This means IPTables can't possibly know which DNS name a client is connecting to, it only knows which IP the client connects to.

If you specify `--destination sub.domain.com` as a parameter, IPTables will simply do a name look up to the IP that corresponds to this name, and then use the IP in it's rules.

If your port 1000 serves HTTP it would be possible to configure an HTTP server on that port to not handle requests to domains other than sub.domain.com, but IPTables doesn't have the necessary information to this.

If you could put sub.domain.com and sub.domain2.com onto two different IPs on the same server, then IPTables would be able to deny access to one but not to the other, because it could decide based on the IP.

This illustrates nicely that the `Domain Name System` is on top of `Transport` (TCP) and `Internet` (IP), for more details you can read the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) about it:

[image: ISO OSI]

Comment: might want to mention the OSI model, perhaps showing which layers correspond to what he wants to do vs. what iptables will allow you to do? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model

Comment: @slm right, done

Comment: Thanks, this question has come up enough times that answering it like this will likely help others who don't understand the stack and where things can/can't be done 8-)

Comment: I feel silly now. I should have known that iptables wasn't the right tool... I mean, it's pretty much in the name :) Thanks for the thorough answer.